# Using Next Element Sibling in Aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a use case where when a user hovers the mouse over an image it should disappear and sibling image should be displayed. When I tried to do with CSS I got a bad flicker effect. I thought I would try to do it using the HTML hidden attribute but I don't seem to be able to select the sibling of the

Can anyone take a look at this and tell me where I went wrong. Much appreciated.  It seems to work with setting the hidden attribute but with removing it.

Sample Component Markup

```
<div class="slds-large-size_4-of-12 slds-align--absolute-center">
            <img  src="{!v.content.Public_Three_Up_Document2_URL__c}" onmouseenter="{!c.handleMouseOver}" onmouseout="{!c.handleMouseOut}"/>
            <img  src="{!v.content.Public_Hover_URL2__c}" hidden="true"/>
        </div>
```

Controller methods

```
 handleMouseOver: function (component, event, controller) {
        console.log('handle mouse over called')
        const primaryImg = event.target;
        const secondaryImage  = primaryImg.nextElementSibling;
        primaryImg.setAttribute('hidden', true);
        secondaryImage.setAttribute('hidden', false);
    },

    handleMouseOut:function (component, event, controller) {
      const primaryImg = event.target;
      const secondaryImg = primaryImg.nextElementSibling;
      primaryImg.setAttribute('hidden', false);
      secondaryImg.setAttribute('hidden', true)
    },
```

I have also tried to implement this using something like this and get a bad flicker effect.

```
handleMouseOver: function (component, event, controller) {
        console.log('handle mouse over called')
        const primaryImg = event.target;
        const secondaryImage  = primaryImg.nextElementSibling;
        $A.util.toggleClass(primaryImg, "hide");
        $A.util.toggleClass(secondaryImage, "hide");        
    },

    handleMouseOut:function (component, event, controller) {
      const primaryImg = event.target;
      const secondaryImg = primaryImg.nextElementSibling;
      $A.util.toggleClass(primaryImg, "hide");
      $A.util.toggleClass(secondaryImg, "hide");          
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use plain CSS:

```
<div class="toggleImage">
    <img  src="{!v.content.Public_Three_Up_Document2_URL__c}" />
    <img  src="{!v.content.Public_Hover_URL2__c}" />
</div>
```

---

```
.THIS .toggleImage img + img {
    display: none;
}
.THIS .toggleImage:hover img {
    display: none;
}
.THIS .toggleImage:hover img + img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

---

You don't need any script at all, and this should be more efficient. If instead, you simply want to use a script after all, use the div as a wrapper instead.

Note that by setting onmouseout on the first img, the flickering comes from the fact that it will be triggered as soon as the mouse moves a single pixel, and on the next move of a pixel, the onmouseover will fire again.

Here's the script alternative:

```
<div class="slds-large-size_4-of-12 slds-align--absolute-center" onmouseenter="{!c.handleMouseOver}" onmouseout="{!c.handleMouseOut}">
    <img  src="{!v.content.Public_Three_Up_Document2_URL__c}" />
    <img class="slds-hide" src="{!v.content.Public_Hover_URL2__c}" />
</div>
```

---

```
handleMouseOver: function(component, event, helper) {
    var imgs = event.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('img');
    imgs[0].classList.add('slds-hide');
    imgs[1].classList.remove('slds-hide');
}
handleMouseOut: function(component, event, helper) {
    var imgs = event.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('img');
    imgs[0].classList.remove('slds-hide');
    imgs[1].classList.add('slds-hide');
}
```

Comment: Thank, as always SFDXfox. When I used CSS I was also getting the flicker. But It was probably related to the same issues.